# Synchronize Seadragon Ajax Images

Tags: javascript, deepzoom, seadragon

I need to synchronize multiple Seadragon images.

I found this post from Beck Johnson regarding the synchronization of deep zoom Seadragon images. He said he did this by: "Each Seadragon.Viewer is opened, then stashed in an array..."

https://getsatisfaction.com/livelabs/topics/synchronize_panning_zooming_for_multiple_images_with_seadragon

However, the otherViewer var returns as undefined.

```
var zoomContainers = new Array();

    var viewer = new Seadragon.Viewer("container");
    viewer.openDzi("logo.dzi");


    var viewer2 = new Seadragon.Viewer("container2");
    viewer2.openDzi("logo.dzi");

    zoomContainers.push(viewer);
    zoomContainers.push(viewer2);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're pushing your viewers directly into zoomContainers, so to access them, you just do `zoomContainers[i]` rather than `zoomContainers[i].viewer`.

By the way, Seadragon Ajax is actively developed as OpenSeadragon these days, now on version 1.1.0:

http://openseadragon.github.io/